# Are there any multi-country EU polls on the Russian-language policies of former Soviet republics that are either full EU members or EU associates?

Tags: european-union, ukraine, public-opinion, languages

Are there any multi-country EU polls (like those conducted by Eurostat or Pew, although not necessarily just by those orgs) on the topic of Russian-language policies in former Soviet republics that are either full EU members or EU associates?

Basically, I'd like to know how the language policies of the countries with significant Russian-speaking minorities (especially the Baltics and Ukraine) are perceived by "average" EU citizens outside those countries where the said minorities reside.

I can easily find dozens of papers written by academics on the issue of the treatment of the Russian minorities in said countries, and likewise some statements by human rights organizations, but (here) I'm interested/asking how this Russian language issue is perceived on the street rather than in the "ivory towers" or in human-rights activist/specialist circles. I know that the topic might not be too suitable for polling, because informed answers require knowledge that might not easily exist in the general EU public, especially given changes over time in legislation in the countries with Russian minorities, how that legislation is implemented in practice etc. Nevertheless, just on the level of sentiment [well informed or not], I think it would be interesting to know how this issue is perceived more broadly in the EU, e.g. are Russian speakers perceived as getting a "fair treatment" or not (or "I don't know"), if you ask a random EU citizen on the street. More recent polls would be preferable.

Comment: To have the ful picture Moldova and posibly Georgia should be also mentioned in this context.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/283934560_Comparison_of_language_policies_in_the_post-Soviet_Union_countries_on_the_European_continent?

Comment: @convert: that only has a poll taken within Moldova (p. 62). I have no doubt more such single-country polls exist in those countries that have a significant Russian minority. I'm mostly interested how the problem is perceived by outsiders in the rest of the EU.

Comment: I'm German and I consider myself politically fairly well informed. I know that the Baltics have significant Russian speaking minorities but I have no idea what Baltic policies towards the Russian language are much less an opinion on whether such policies are good or bad. I don't think this topic can be polled because only people who have some specific connection to the issue will have any knowledge or opinion about it.

Comment: Maybe you could point to some of the academic findings too?  I confess I am not sure what a policy should be in this case:  should a country treat Russian as any different than any other language that is not *native* to the area?  i.e. Should it be taught in school in any other way than a foreign language elective?  Should it be usable on official communication?  What other policy should exist, besides not discriminating against its *private* use?  I mean, I am sure Russia is going to argue it's special and so will Russian-speakers, but how is it actually different from another language?

Comment: "Minorities" tag, as it is defined in the tool-tip, is not applicable to this question.  I am going to remove it.  The claim of groups speaking Russian, as their 1st language, being disadvantaged is a subject of active debate and should not be asserted with tags unless there is some evidence for it provided in the question.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: Sure; see convert's link for a typical academic paper. Or https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/13670050.2015.1115004?journalCode=rbeb20  or https://books.google.com/books?id=QeXZYdjB_H0C (which is book-length) Summarizing their findings or recommendations (here) would a tall order though. And https://www.hrw.org/news/2022/01/19/new-language-requirement-raises-concerns-ukraine or https://www.amnesty.org/en/documents/eur51/002/2006/en/ for the latter kind of statements from human-rights groups. (The last one is fairly dated.)

Comment: @Fizz I did say it's a matter of public debate.  That means there are claims on both sides.  I am actually thinking of writing a frame-challenge answer about Ukraine.  But I am not sure if you care for particular tidbit.  Also the AI report is from 2006.  A few things have happened since then.

Comment: @wrod seems to me *minorities* is a valid tag usage here, except that the explanation about [minorities] is too restrictive/specific.  [Asking on meta](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6330/is-the-minorities-tag-correctly-annotated).  If we go strictly by tag description, you're right.  Going by general accepted meaning of the word however the tag's use seems to clarify this question.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica which is a problem, especially right now, during a hot war with so much war propaganda being pushed (as is expected because it's life and death struggle). Asserting untoward behavior by Ukraine is a big part of RF's strategy to attempt to sway West's public opinion from supplying weapons for Ukraine's defense. If the tag description is made less accusatory then maybe it would be more fitting, but I am not convinced that Russian-speaking population is an actual minority in Ukraine. There is evidence that Russian-avoidance is a choice rather than a forced behavior.

Comment: Oh, I agree.  Russian minorities in Baltics don't necessarily qualify for special treatments and are not necessarily discriminated officially against, including linguistically.  Or maybe they are.  They are still "minorities" in a more neutral use of the term however, regardless of whether they are being discriminated against.  Linguistic concerns are often tied to minority groups, whether those concerns are justified or not.  And, yes, whining about ill-treatment of "Russian brothers" is as fresh as my gym socks, Kremlin-wise.